# In what order should one release COM objects and garbage collect?

Tags: c#, com, garbage-collection

There are lots of questions on SO regarding the releasing COM objects and garbage collection but nothing I could find that address this question specifically.

When releasing COM objects (specifically Excel Interop in this case), in what order should I be releasing the reference and calling garbage collection?

In some places (such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1893653/976080)) I have seen this:

```
Marshall.FinalReleaseComObject(obj);
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

And in others (such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/159419/976080)) this:

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
Marshall.FinalReleaseComObject(obj);
```

Or doesn't it matter and I'm worrying about nothing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject() releases the underlying COM interface pointer.

GC.Collect() and GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers() causes the finalizer for a COM wrapper to be called, which calls FinalReleaseComObject().

So what makes no sense is to do it *both* ways.  Pick one or the other.

The trouble with explicitly calling FinalReleaseComObject() is that it will only work when you call it for **all** the interface pointers.  The Office program will keep running if you miss just one of them.  That's *very* easy to do, especially the syntax sugar allowed in C# version 4 makes it likely.  An expression like `range = sheet.Cells[1, 1]`, very common in Excel interop code.  There's a hidden Range interface reference there that you never explicitly store anywhere.  So you can't release it either.

That's not a problem with GC.Collect(), it can see them.  It is however not entirely without trouble either, it will only collect and run the finalizer when your program has no reference to the interface anymore.  Which is definitely what's wrong with your second snippet.  And which tends to go wrong when you debug your program, the debugger extends the lifetime of local object references to the end of the method.  Also the time you look at Taskmgr and yell "die dammit!"

The usual advice for GC.Collect() applies here as well.  Keep your program running and perform work.  The normal thing happens, you'll trigger a garbage collection and that releases the COM wrappers as well.  And the Office program will exit.  It just doesn't happen instantly, it will happen eventually.

Comment: Thanks Hans, that clears things up a bit. Just to clarify, you suggest getting rid of the `FinalReleaseComObject()` calls and keeping the `GC.Collect()` and `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()` calls since they call the former anyway? Or does your last paragraph suggest getting rid of all of it and letting it all happen eventually?

Comment: Quote: `Keep your program running and perform work`, it will all come to a good end when you do.

Answer (score 1):

Reference counting mechanism that is used by COM is another way of automatic memory management but with slightly different impact on memory and behavior.

Any reference counting implementation provide deterministic behavior for resource cleanup. This means that right after call to `Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject()` all resources (memory and other resources) related to the COM object would be reclaimed.

This means that if we have additional managed objects and you want to reclaim them as quickly as possible, you should release COM object first and only after that call `GC.Collect` method.